# Is there a way to organize Delphi XE2/XE5 tabs editor in multitabs?

Tags: delphi, tabs, ide, delphi-xe2

I have a lot of files to keep open, and the current single line of tabs is just difficult. I see that GExperts and CNPack does not have that (unless I missed that).

Is there any trick to achieve that, or any other suggestion that I could have more tabs visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TIDEGradientTabSet` (if it's still used in modern Delphi) doesn't support multiline view, so the only option for those IDE experts could be making own tab set control hiding the original one.

Alternatives are:

- On the far right of the tabs is a small down arrow. Press that, and you'll see a list of all the files that are open in the editor;
- Pressing `Ctrl+B` will open up a dialog to select a tab;
- TMS has a free tool [AltTab](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/alttab.asp) but it did not get update for while. That was exactly what was needed for Delphi IDE;

Comment: Despite not being updated since 2007, [AltTab](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/alttab.asp) works fine with much later versions (checked on XE2). Just use "[Delphi 7](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/DOWNLOAD/AGALTTAB.ZIP)" download, not those for Delphi 2006/2007